# Auto starting rc at startup

Tags: ubuntu, boot, init.d, init, linux

So here are the steps i am following . So i add a conf file inside

```
/etc/init.d/myconffile
```

And then to get System start/stop links i have to use the command

```
sudo update-rc.d myconffile defaults 99 2 3 4 5
```

And then if i reboot Ubuntu server the system will auto start the service . But what i want is that when the system starts for the first time this service is started . Is there a way to do it . I have been reading all around about this but was not able to find anything. Please let me know if you can think of a way

Comment: What is exactly that you want? Please explain it better.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea. Sounds like one of those programs, where you are told to reboot to complete installation. Ubuntu users expect better than that. So why would you make the first boot after your package is installed different from the following? Keep in mind, that after the service has been installed, it could be several months before the server is rebooted the next time.

Answer (score 1):

I might not understand your question correctly, but:

If you want to to it during the "initial setup" of the server you might need some configuration management tool like chef or puppet.

Otherwise to just start it after you installed the service without the need of a reboot:

`/etc/init.d/myservice start` or `service myservice start`

will most likely start it.

Comment: I want the start to be automated. Like say the dnsservice or ssh service. We dont run an update-rc on them. So when we start the box, we have the service running. Here we will need to issue update-rc command and then on reboot we get the service started automatically. I wanted to skip this update-rc command

Comment: so read the update-rc script and execute the command executed there...